# Calling an android activity using ListView item click

Tags: android, listview

Hy guys i am developing an android app its going well but i am stuck now.I am trying to call activities when a listview item is clicked it must open a specific activity according to the details of the listview item details.Here is my code in a method.

```
private void updateList() {
    // For a ListActivity we need to set the List Adapter, and in order to do
    //that, we need to create a ListAdapter.  This SimpleAdapter,
    //will utilize our updated Hashmapped ArrayList, 
    //use our single_post xml template for each item in our list,
    //and place the appropriate info from the list to the
    //correct GUI id.  Order is important here.
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mOutletsList,
    R.layout.single_outlet, new String[] { TAG_OUTLET_NAME,     TAG_SPARKLING_CHANNEL, 

TAG_SPARKLING_CLASSIFICATION, TAG_CLASS}, new int[]
                    { R.id.outlet_name,     R.id.sparkling_channel, R.id.sparkling_classification, 

 R.id.cls_state});

    // I shouldn't have to comment on this one:
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // Optional: when the user clicks a list item we 
    //could do something.  However, we will choose
    //to do nothing...
    final ListView lv = getListView();  
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {


            HashMap<String, String>map = (HashMap<String, String>)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);


            String foutname = map.get(TAG_OUTLET_NAME);
            String fchannel = map.get(TAG_SPARKLING_CHANNEL);
            String fclass = map.get(TAG_SPARKLING_CLASSIFICATION);
            String fclass_state = map.get(TAG_CLASS);

            String compr = "GDB";
            String compr2 = "QSRG"

            if(compr == fclass_state){


            Intent i = new Intent(OutletsList.this, GdgScoreSheeet.class);
            i.putExtra("outlt", foutname);
            i.putExtra("chnl", fchannel);
            i.putExtra("cls", fclass);
            i.putExtra("clsstate", fclass_state);
            startActivity(i);
            }
            if(compr2 == fclass_state){
            Intent i = new Intent(OutletsList.this, QsrgScoreSheeet.class);
            i.putExtra("outlt", foutname);
            i.putExtra("chnl", fchannel);
            i.putExtra("cls", fclass);
            i.putExtra("clsstate", fclass_state);
            startActivity(i);

            }



        }

    });
}
```

When i click its showing this error in the logcat, java.lang.ClassCastExeption: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String.Ypur help is greatly appreciated or even alternative code and solutions.Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are casting a HashMap to a String which will give you an error of `ClassCastExeption`

**problem:**

This code will return a String not a HashMap

```
parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Base from your `SimpleAdapter` you added a Array of `String` not a HashMap to each of the item in the ListView.

```
 new SimpleAdapter(this, mOutletsList,
                   R.layout.single_outlet, 
                   new String[] { TAG_OUTLET_NAME, TAG_SPARKLING_CHANNEL, TAG_SPARKLING_CLASSIFICATION, TAG_CLASS}, 
                   new int[]{ R.id.outlet_name,     R.id.sparkling_channel, R.id.sparkling_classification, R.id.cls_state});
```

**solution 1**

There is no way to cast it to HashMap unless you make a BaseAdapter for it, you can [click here](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/) to learn to make adapter.

**solution 2**

Other solution is to just get all the array of items from the ListView

```
        String foutname = parent.getItemAtPosition(0);
        String fchannel = parent.getItemAtPosition(1);
        String fclass = parent.getItemAtPosition(2);
        String fclass_state = parent.getItemAtPosition(3);
```

Comment: Ok so i should change my hash mapings with what you wrote above?

Comment: @user3652315 you cant get hashmap from your code, follow solution1 if you want to implement Hashmapping to ListView

Comment: @user3652315 the solution 2 is to just get all the data you added in your ListView thats basically what you are doing in your current code

Answer (score 0):

may be this could help -

```
String classes[]="Start","Send","Tabs","Browser","Flipper","SharedPrefs","InternalData","Sqlite","Checking"};
```

// make list view from this string array

//on list item clicked use this... note the first line in try block.

```
String cheese=classes[position];
    try{
        Class cl=Class.forName("com.example.test."+cheese);
        Intent i=new Intent(Menu.this,cl);
        startActivity(i);
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){}
```

Comment: I am not sure for you, but I do it like this.

Comment: Thanks Ronn i wish i could do that but my data is coming from a data base.